# Active class for my flexslider in WordPress

Tags: loop, jquery

I'm calling images with a wordpress loop to display in a flexslider on the home page.

However, the active class for the thumbnails of the slider aren't working in tandem with the slideshow -- I can't click on thumbnails to view the corresponding larger slideshow image. Instead when I click on the thumbnails all the images in the slider disappear.

I believe it has something to do with setting the active class on the thumbnails - and since it isn't hard coded, I'm trying to modify the flexslider jquery to add the active class to the thumbnails

[test site](http://www.ccbcreative.com/three-river/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

// Default FlexSlider parameters
if (typeof fs_params == 'undefined') {
    fs_params = {animation: 'fade', controlNav: true, directionNav: true, slideshow: false, pauseOnAction: true, pauseOnHover: false, animationSpeed: 600, slideshowSpeed: 7000};
}

// Homepage FlexSlider parameters
if (typeof fs_params_homepage == 'undefined') {
    fs_params_homepage = {animation: 'fade', controlNav: true, directionNav: true, slideshow: true, pauseOnAction: false, pauseOnHover: true, animationSpeed: 600, slideshowSpeed: 7000};
}

// Note: fs_params / fs_params_homepage can be overwritten by setting its value in an html file


// *** FLEXSLIDER INITIALIZATION
$('.flexslider').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.is('#home-slider')) {

        // Callback function: fires asynchronously with each slider animation
        fs_params_homepage.before = function(slider){
            var next_index = slider.animatingTo + 1,
                current_index = slider.currentSlide + 1,
                $next_caption = $('.slider-caption div[id=caption'+next_index+']'),
                $current_caption = $('.slider-caption div[id=caption'+current_index+']');

            $('.slider-menu li').removeClass('active').siblings().find('a')
                    .filter(function () {
                        return $(this).attr('href') == '#slide'+next_index;
                    }).parent().addClass('active');

            if ($('html').hasClass('ie8')) { // IE8 hack
                $current_caption.hide();
            }
            $current_caption.fadeOut(400, 'swing', function() {
                if ($('html').hasClass('ie8')) { // IE8 hack
                    $next_caption.show();
                } else {
                    $next_caption.fadeIn(300, 'swing');
                }
                setCaptionHeight($next_caption);
            });
        };

        // Callback function: fires after each slider animation completes
        fs_params_homepage.after = function(slider){

        };

        // Init homepage slider:

        // full-width slider with center-aligned image
        if ($this.parent().parent().parent().parent().hasClass('full-width-image')) {
            if ($this.attr('data-slideshow') == 'yes') { fs_params_homepage.slideshow = true; }
            if ($this.attr('data-slideshow') == 'no') { fs_params_homepage.slideshow = false; }
            if ($this.attr('data-animation') == 'fade') { fs_params_homepage.animation = 'fade'; }
            if ($this.attr('data-animation') == 'slide') { fs_params_homepage.animation = 'slide'; }
            if ($this.attr('data-control-nav') == 'yes') { fs_params_homepage.controlNav = true; }
            if ($this.attr('data-control-nav') == 'no') { fs_params_homepage.controlNav = false; }
            if ($this.attr('data-direction-nav') == 'yes') { fs_params_homepage.directionNav = true; }
            if ($this.attr('data-direction-nav') == 'no') { fs_params_homepage.directionNav = false; }
            if ($this.attr('data-pause-on-action') == 'yes') { fs_params_homepage.pauseOnAction = true; }
            if ($this.attr('data-pause-on-action') == 'no') { fs_params_homepage.pauseOnAction = false; }
        }

        // slider with right-aligned image
        else {
            fs_params_homepage.animation = 'fade';
        }

        if ($this.attr('data-slideshow-speed') > 0) { fs_params_homepage.slideshowSpeed = $this.attr('data-slideshow-speed'); }
        $this.flexslider(fs_params_homepage);
    }

    else {
        // Init default slider
        var params = $.extend({}, fs_params);
        if ($this.attr('data-slideshow') == 'yes') { params.slideshow = true; }
        if ($this.attr('data-slideshow') == 'no') { params.slideshow = false; }
        if ($this.attr('data-slideshow-speed') > 0) { params.slideshowSpeed = $this.attr('data-slideshow-speed'); }
        if ($this.attr('data-animation') == 'fade') { params.animation = 'fade'; }
        if ($this.attr('data-animation') == 'slide') { params.animation = 'slide'; }
        if ($this.attr('data-control-nav') == 'yes') { params.controlNav = true; }
        if ($this.attr('data-control-nav') == 'no') { params.controlNav = false; }
        if ($this.attr('data-direction-nav') == 'yes') { params.directionNav = true; }
        if ($this.attr('data-direction-nav') == 'no') { params.directionNav = false; }
        if ($this.attr('data-pause-on-action') == 'yes') { params.pauseOnAction = true; }
        if ($this.attr('data-pause-on-action') == 'no') { params.pauseOnAction = false; }
        $this.flexslider(params);
    }

});


// *** HOMEPAGE SLIDER
$homeSlider = $('#home-slider').data('flexslider');

// Slider menu
$('.slider-menu li').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var slide_index = $('a', this).attr('href').substr(6) - 1;
    $homeSlider.flexslider(slide_index);
    return false; // IE9 hack
});

// Position the right side navigation ("right-side-nav" class)
function positionRightSideNav() {
    if ($(window).width() >= 768) {
        var homeHero_x = 0.5 * ($(window).width() - $('#home-hero').width()),
            heroImage_marginLeft = parseInt($('#home-hero .hero-image').css('margin-left')),
            col_marginLeft = parseInt($('#home-hero-content .columns').css('margin-left')),
            rightSideNav_width = $('#home-slider.right-side-nav .flex-direction-nav a').width(),
            navLeft = $(window).width() - (homeHero_x + col_marginLeft + heroImage_marginLeft) - rightSideNav_width;
        $('#home-slider.right-side-nav .flex-direction-nav a').css('left', navLeft + 'px');
    } else {
        $('#home-slider.right-side-nav .flex-direction-nav a').css('left', '');
    }
}
```

**wp-query for large slideshow images:**

```
<div class="hero-image">
                    <div id="home-slider" class="flexslider right-side-nav">
                        <ul class="slides">

<?php    

$attachments = get_children(array('post_parent' => 107, 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'posts_per_page' => 7, 'order' => 'DESC' ));

if ($attachments) {

    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment_id => $attachment ) {

        echo '<li id="slide'.$attachment_id.'" >';
        echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, 'home-slider');
        echo '</li>';
    }

} // end see if images

 wp_reset_postdata();

  ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**and then wp-query for thumbs:**

```
<?php    

$thumbs = get_children(array('post_parent' => 107, 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'posts_per_page' => 7, 'order' => 'DESC' ));

if ($thumbs) { // if there are images attached to posting, start the flexslider markup

    foreach ( $thumbs as $attachment_id => $thumb ) { // create the list items for images with captions

        echo '<li>';
        echo '<a href="#slide'.$attachment_id.'" >';
        echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, 'home-slider-thumb');
        echo '</a>';
        echo '</li>';
    }

} // end see if images

wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code here is the problem-

```
$('.slider-menu li').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var slide_index = $('a', this).attr('href').substr(6) - 1;
    $homeSlider.flexslider(slide_index);
    return false; // IE9 hack
});
```

In your html, you're setting your IDs to `slide` plus the attachment ID, then telling flexslider to animate to that slide. Except flexslider is expecting a *slide position* (1st slide, 2nd slide, etc.), not an element ID. You should instead use the index of the clicked li-

```
$('.slider-menu li').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $homeSlider.flexslider( $(this).index() );
    return false; // IE9 hack
});
```

Also note that flexslider can do all this stuff for you automagically if you create a carousel for the thumbs, and set the carousel `asNavFor` for the slider.

Comment: Yes! I changed the jquery to use the index, works perfectly... I was not looking at this portion - and my js jquery isn't the best. Thank you so very much!

Answer (score 0):

`.active` class of flexslider is not specific to WordPress, so off-topic here. BTW, a simple `WP_Query()`, `get_posts()`, `get_children()` etc. never affects the flexslider performance. What you have to follow is the syntax provided by the flexslider. Please note:

```
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    //loop starts
       <li>
         <img src="slide1.jpg" />
       </li>
    //loop ends
  </ul>
</div>
```

The `ul.slides` is important.

And the `active` class is absent because somehow the JS is not triggered correctly. So to debug JS issue (if any) you can use the browser's developer console. A simple jQuery worked for me in many of my projects:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: "thumbnails"
  });
});
```

Please check:

- A [noConflict wrapper](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers) is necessary or not
- jQuery is [enqueued](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) before the `flexslider.min.js`
- Your custom JS code enqueued properly and loads after loading the DOM
- And, `flexslider.css` is also enqueued in the `<head>` - sometime it's important

***HEY!*** `.flex-active` is the class that loads in the thumbnail image (`<img>`), **NOT** in the `<li>` ([check here](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-controlnav.html))

And `wp_reset_postdata()` is not necessary for [`get_children()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children) query. :)

Comment: noConflict wrapper is needed

Comment: If you found the answer helpful, you are suggested to check to checkmark on the left to accept the answer. It'll help other identify helpful answer.

Comment: thank you for taking a look at the issue. I couldn't finish my comment earlier - I intended to say that it wasn't about a noConflict wrapper. JQuery is enqueued first. All is working as it should, it's just that the active class was initially hard coded in html and now that I am using dynamic images, I can't modify the flexslider jquery properly to find the thumbnail li and place a class of active. That's all it needs I believe. But I appreciate you taking a look at all the code.

Comment: What about the simple jQuery code I gave you instead of yours?  Did you try 'em?

Comment: thanks for checking back. I did try the jquery code you gave me. It's just that this html template (that I've developed into a wordpress theme) has modified flexslider jquery to the point that I can't figure out how to rework the jquery to work in tandem with the WP construct. So I will likely modify the html and get a clean copy of flexslider jquery. (With this modified jquery a class of active is used to fire the thumbnails and since images are dynamically generated, I need a way to add active class, which I've tried in flexslider w no luck yet.)

Comment: can I have live link? Have you seen this line: ***HEY!** .flex-active is the class that loads in the thumbnail image (<img>), NOT in the <li>*

Comment: I updated the jquery and added the link to the test site to my question. Can that the modified, though, the flex-active class...